# Generated barcode is coming so blurred that it's not scannable

Tags: python, barcode, reportlab

I am trying to generate barcode using following code but the output is blurry and non readable.

```
def barcode(self, request, pk):
    d = BarCodeGenerator(pk)
    binaryStuff = d.asString('gif')
    return HttpResponse(binaryStuff, 'image/gif')`
```

and `BarCodeGenerator` class

```
class BarCodeGenerator(Drawing):
    def __init__(self, text_value, *args, **kw):
        barcode = createBarcodeDrawing('Code128', value=text_value,  barHeight=10*mm, humanReadable=False)
        Drawing.__init__(self,barcode.width,barcode.height,*args,**kw)
        self.add(barcode, name='barcode')
```

Comment: You should be using `super()` over calling the parent classes `__init__()` directly. IT also doesn't seem to be doing anything. Does it automatically write to a file or something?

Comment: thanks for the replay. It is not writing to any file but on an api call it returns the image to client

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are stacking `Drawing` objects. In order to get the binary Gif of the barcode it is sufficient to just do:

```
# Create barcode with the size based on barHeight and barWidth
barcode = createBarcodeDrawing('Code128', value="data", barHeight=10 * cm, barWidth=2 * mm)

# Create the gif binary for the barcode Gif
binary = barcode.asString('gif')

# Write is to a file for easy testing
newFile = open("barcode.gif", "wb")
newFile.write(binary)
```

The result in that case looks like this, which should be scanable. If you need to adjust the size, change the `barHeight` and `barWidth` instead of re-sizing the image as that can make the edges fussy thus unscanable.
[image: Barcode example]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me check and i will let u know if it works.

Comment: Did it work? Otherwise you might want to check whether the image is compressed somewhere in you pipeline.